# Probability of sum of normal distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be independent standard normal random variables. Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. How do I analyze $P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty S_n<\sqrt n$)? If the $S_n$ were independent, then I can just split the probability into a product, but I know the $S_n$ are not independent. I have no idea how to proceed. Are there inequalities to give me an upper bound?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm